# simplify and ctx-solver-simplify in Java (or C#)

Tags: z3

According to [simplification in Z3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14057349/simplification-in-z3), there are two ways to simplify an expression in Z3: `simplify` and `ctx-solver-simplify` When using the Java api, I am only able to find the method `simplify()` on the `com.microsoft.z3.Expr` class. How can I use the `ctx-solver-simplify` method? It does not seem to exist in the `Solver` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a tactic, see [this overview](https://web.archive.org/web/20190206110824/http://rise4fun.com/z3/tutorialcontent/strategies).

See this answer for an example in Java, as well as a comparison between using tactics or the main solver:

[How to call Z3 properly from Java program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19616276/how-to-call-z3-properly-from-java-program)

To use the `ctx-solver-simplify` tactic from Java, create the object with:

`Tactic css = ctx.MkTactic("ctx-solver-simplify")`

where `ctx` is a Z3 Context object.

Comment: So how do I then simplify an expression? Could you create an example? I seem to have to construct a goal, but I do not know what parameters to give.

Comment: Here's a minimal example in the Z3 .NET API using a different tactic (quantifier elimination), but the objects (maybe modulo minor renaming) and steps are the same for the Java API, the result of the simplification will be in the ApplyResult object's Subgoals field, then from there you need to iterate over the subgoals to recreate an expression; it's a bit tedious: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12301908/how-to-use-elim-quantifiers-using-net-api-in-z3/12303067#12303067